# Ruby - Variables inside hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following header which I am passing for http request.

```
s = { 
    'user-principal' => '{"userName":"rootname","password":"rootpassword"}', 
    'Accept' => 'application/json', 
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 
}
```

I don't want to pass the username and password directly. Instead I have `UName` and `PASS` variables which have encrypted username and password respectively. How should I pass those variables in the header hash?

Comment: `s['user-principal']['password'] = PASS` and `s['user-principal]['userName'] = UName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `user-principal` looks like a **JSON string**, you can construct it by passing a hash to **`JSON.dump`**. This will ensure that any special characters in `UName` and `PASS` are properly escaped:

```
s = { 
  'user-principal' => JSON.dump(
    'userName' => UName,
    'password' => PASS
  ),
  'Accept' => 'application/json', 
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 
}
```